# Flutter Test Mock GraphQL Mutation result

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, flutter-test, flutter-graphql

I'm trying to create widget tests for a flutter application using GraphQL.
What I want to do is to test the behaviour of the app which depends on the result of a GraphQL Mutation on a user action.

This is a very simple example of the app:

```dart
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget return Container(
    child: Mutation(
      options: myMutationOptions,
      onCompleted: (dynamic result) {
        final bool myBool = result['bool'] as bool;
        if (myBool) {
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));
        } else {
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdScreen()));
        }
      },
      builder: (RunMutation runMutation, QueryResult queryResult) {
       return FlatButton(
         child: Text('Button'),
         onPressed: () async {
           await runMutation(myParameters).networkResult;
         },
       );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

What I would like to do is to mock the result of the mutation so in my widget tests, I can test that the button redirects to the `SecondScreen` or `ThirdScreen` depending of the result `myBool`.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to successfully mock a GraphQL Mutation. Here is how I did it, it is inspired from @Gpack's comment but I had to add some modifications and details to it.

To make it easy to use I created a wrapper widget `GraphQLMutationMocker` :

```dart
class MockClient extends Mock implements Client {
  MockClient({
    this.mockedResult,
    this.mockedStatus = 200,
  });
  final Map<String, dynamic> mockedResult;
  final int mockedStatus;

  @override
  Future<StreamedResponse> send(BaseRequest request) {
    return Future<StreamedResponse>.value(
      StreamedResponse(
        Stream.value(utf8.encode(jsonEncode(mockedResult))),
        mockedStatus,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GraphQLMutationMocker extends StatelessWidget {
  const GraphQLMutationMocker({
    @required this.child,
    this.mockedResult = const {},
    this.mockedStatus = 200,
    this.url = 'http://url',
    this.storagePrefix = 'test',
  });
  final Widget child;

  final Map<String, dynamic> mockedResult;

  final int mockedStatus;

  final String url;

  final String storagePrefix;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mockClient = MockClient(
      mockedResult: mockedResult,
      mockedStatus: mockedStatus,
    );
    final httpLink = HttpLink(
      uri: url,
      httpClient: mockClient,
    );
    final graphQLClient = ValueNotifier(
      GraphQLClient(
        cache: InMemoryCache(storagePrefix: storagePrefix),
        link: httpLink,
      ),
    );
    return GraphQLProvider(
      client: graphQLClient,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Then it was pretty easy to write the tests

```dart
group('Test mutation', () {
  
  testWidgets('It should redirect to SecondScreen', (WidgetTester tester) async {

    await tester.pumpWidget(GraphQLMutationMocker(
      mockedResult: <String, dynamic>{
        'data': {
          'bool': true,
        },
      },
      child: FirstScreen(),
    ));
    // Click on button
    await tester.tap(find.text('Button'));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // Check I'm on the right screen
    expect(find.byType(SecondScreen), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.byType(ThirdScreen), findsNothing);
  });

  testWidgets('It should redirect to ThirdScreen', (WidgetTester tester) async {

    await tester.pumpWidget(GraphQLMutationMocker(
      mockedResult: <String, dynamic>{
        'data': {
          'bool': false,
        },
      },
      child: FirstScreen(),
    ));
    // Click on button
    await tester.tap(find.text('Button'));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    
    // Check I'm on the right screen
    expect(find.byType(SecondScreen), findsNothing);
    expect(find.byType(ThirdScreen), findsOneWidget);
  });
})
```

Comment: From where do you import the Mock class?

Comment: It is the [mockito package](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito)

Comment: For anyone who was confused with the Mock class. The mockito package ^5.0.0 has a new class called Fake which you'll have to use here.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a mock of http.Client like in the flutter [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking)
2. In your test, wrap your `FirstScreen` in a GraphqlProvider like so:

```dart
class MockHttpClient extends Mock implements Client {}

group('Test mutation', () {
  MockHttpClient mockHttpClient;
  HttpLink httpLink;
  ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client;

  setUp(() async {
    mockHttpClient = MockHttpClient();
    httpLink = HttpLink(
      uri: 'https://unused/graphql',
      httpClient: mockHttpClient,
    );
    client = ValueNotifier(
      GraphQLClient(
        cache: InMemoryCache(storagePrefix: 'test'),
        link: httpLink,
      ),
    );
  });

  testWidgets('redirects to SecondScreen', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    when(client.send(captureAny)).thenAnswer(/* ... */);
    await tester.pumpWidget(GraphQLProvider(
      client: client,
      child: FirstScreen(),
    ));
    // Click on button
    verify(mockHttpClient.send(any)).called(1);
    // etc.
  });
})
```